# Do we need to share /var/lib/nfs for NFSv4 recovery process?

Tags: high-availability, nfs, recovery

As I read from NFSv4 recovery process, client also held states and can help in rebuilding the NFS state in case NFS server crashes. I am trying to build a active-passive NFS HA using drbd. Do I need to still share the /var/lib/nfs/ folder on drbd between NFS-Servers?

I tried a simple setup. A single NFS-Client and two NFS-Server. Even without sharing the folder, NFS-Client is able to start the recovery process and after end of grace period NFS-Server and NFS-Client are able to do IO.

Comment: This may be a better question for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com).